# how to display calendar control in android?

Tags: android

i need to make an android application to show a calendar control. I have tried to find such a control in the default widgets provided by android, but could not find it.

How to integrate a calendar control in an Android application.

I also want the calendar to enable adding events to specific dates.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: i found the calendar view control but any other way to use calendars which is better then this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ancal](http://code.google.com/p/ancal/) is a good android calendar control. Also an its opensource android control.

Comment: ancal is for android version 1.5. How do i integrate ancal into my android project?

Comment: how do i integrate it with my android project?

Comment: download its sources and integrate that in your project. The code is easy to understand and you will quickly get it working.

Comment: only the apk is availalbe... how do access the class files from the apk. If you have certain code or a site that display sample code, please do tell me...

Comment: You can get source here:http://code.google.com/p/ancal/source/checkout. If you are not a member the you can aceess readonly code.